# Function turns into an endless loop

Tags: php, function

I have a problem with a function I have written in php. As you can see the function uses itself to return an array of the values.

```
    public function getRepeat($day = "array")
{
    if ($day == 'array')
    {//Return an array with the repeated days as values
        foreach (array(1,2,3,4,5,6,0) as $value) 
        {
            if ($this->getRepeat($value))
            {
                $returnArray[] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $returnArray;
    }
    else if (in_array($day, array(1,2,3,4,5,6,0) ))
    {
        if ($day == 1)
            return $this->repeat1;
        if ($day == 2)
            return $this->repeat2;
        if ($day == 3)
            return $this->repeat3;
        if ($day == 4)
            return $this->repeat4;
        if ($day == 5)
            return $this->repeat5;
        if ($day == 6)
            return $this->repeat6;
        if ($day == 0)
            return $this->repeat0;
    }
}
```

As soon as it calls itself to get each of the variables it turns into an endless loop.

What causes this?

Comment: It's not really recursive - it's just kind of hacked to allow you to call one method to do two things.

Comment: Edited out the recursion parts. Thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 5):

You must always think of writing a recursive function in two parts:

1. The base case - at which point do you stop recursing and return a value (i.e. is the list empty)
2. The recursive case - how do you call a function again and how does the input differ from the previous call (i.e. do you send the tail of the list)

Ensuring that these two rules hold should result in a recursive function that terminates given that the input is valid.

Here's a recursive solution - however it's in Java :)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> testVals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    testVals.add(0);
    testVals.add(1);
    testVals.add(2);
    testVals.add(3);
    testVals.add(4);
    testVals.add(5);

    List<Integer> toMatch = new ArrayList<Integer>(testVals);

    List<Integer> matches = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    repeatRec(testVals, matches, toMatch);

    System.out.println("Matches " + matches);
}

public static void repeatRec(List<Integer> toTest, List<Integer> matches, List<Integer> toMatch) {


    if (toTest.isEmpty()) {
        //we are done
        return;
    } else {

        Integer head = toTest.get(0);

        if (toMatch.contains(head)) {
            matches.add(head);

        }

        //could have else here if we're only interested in the first match
        repeatRec(toTest.subList(1, toTest.size()), matches, toMatch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Its simple really, when you think about it.

```
0 == 'any text which does not start with a number'
```

Your last digit 0 will cause an endless loop. So you need to change it to

```
if ($day === 'array')
```

**EDIT**

I also took the liberty to fix up your code:

```
/**
 * @obsolete
 */
public function getRepeat($day = "array")
{
    if ($day === 'array') {
     return $this->getAllRepeat();
}
    return $this->getRepeatByDay($day);

}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->repeat = array_fill(0, 7, '');
}

public function getAllRepeat()
{
    return $this->repeat;
}

public function __get($value) {
    switch ($value) {
        case 'repeat0':
        case 'repeat1':
        case 'repeat2':
        case 'repeat3':
        case 'repeat4':
        case 'repeat5':
        case 'repeat6':
            return $this->getRepeatByDay(intval(substr($value, -1, 1)));
    }
}

public function getRepeatByDay($day)
{
    if (!isset($this->repeat[$day])) {
        return null;
    }
    return $this->repeat[$day];
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's an icky "feature". +1 for OIS, -1 for PHP

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest that perhaps a better solution is:

```
public function getRepeat($day = "array")
{
    foreach (array(1,2,3,4,5,6,0) as $value) 
    {
        $tmp = "repeat".$value;
        if ($this->$tmp)
        {
            $returnArray[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $returnArray;
}
```

As to why your function isn't ending, I'm not sure. Normally I'd do what you're trying with two seperate function calls though, like:

```
public function getRepeat()
{
                foreach (array(1,2,3,4,5,6,0) as $value) 
                {
                        if ($this->getRepeat_r($value))
                        {
                                $returnArray[] = $value;
                        }
                }
                return $returnArray;
}
private function getRepeat_r($day)
{
        if (in_array($day, array(1,2,3,4,5,6,0) ))
        {
                if ($day == 1)
                        return $this->repeat1;
                if ($day == 2)
                        return $this->repeat2;
                if ($day == 3)
                        return $this->repeat3;
                if ($day == 4)
                        return $this->repeat4;
                if ($day == 5)
                        return $this->repeat5;
                if ($day == 6)
                        return $this->repeat6;
                if ($day == 0)
                        return $this->repeat0;
        }
}
```

This makes things easier to read, and more stable besides, just incase PHP interprets something as `"array"` when it shouldn't.

Comment: Infact, this is clearly not a recursive function when called like this, unless repeat1/etc call it, in which case, we really need to see that code.

Comment: Your first example will not work when you request the string reply for a single day. The second example will also require a rewrite of calling code for single days, which is ok except for the function name with _r appended is not descriptive.

Comment: PHP has many functions with `_r` appended meaning recursive. Also, my first example is exactly the same as the OP's, except far less verbose.

Comment: In your first example you can not specify a single day. You will only ge the array. In you second example the function with _r in the name is not recursive.